# Set root path to a nested route, depending on role of users Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, if a signed in user is a Borrower, I want them to be routed to `bank/:id/documents`. I'm not sure how to setup the nested resource here.

I'd like to have something like this:

```
 authenticated :user, lambda { |u| u.role == :teller } do
        root to: 'banks#index', :as => :teller_root
  end

  authenticated :user, lambda { |u| u.role == :borrower } do
    root to: 'banks/:id/documents', :as => :borrower_root
  end
```

The first route works, but I don't know how to route the second one. It's basically just a random attempt to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a `RootsController` and in its index action added logic to decide what the root path should be. And then in my routes file I just set root to `root :to => "roots#index`. This appears to work.